# How to get parameters from store's url Flutter?

Tags: flutter, app-store

I want to get parameters from url when I open app.

For example

```
https://apps.apple.com/app/id16385122342?param1=1&param2=2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For flutter web:

```
String param = Uri.base.queryParameters['param1'];
```

Comment: Thank you @Sergio Clemente for your answer. any solution for mobile?

Comment: How the URL come to your app?